# SDL2 makefile error

Tags: c, linker-errors, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a makefile for my SDL2 project. But the linker can't find "-lSDL2". I'm using GCC 4.9.2.

Here is the makefile:

```
# Files to be compiled
OBJS = main.c

# Compiler
CC = gcc

# Include paths
INCLUDE_PATHS = -ID:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2

# Library paths
LIBRARY_PATHS = -LD:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

# Compiler flags
COMPILER_FLAGS = -Wall

# Linker flags
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

# Executable file
OBJ_NAME = main

# Compile command
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(LIBRARY_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

And here are the errors I get when I run the "make" command:

```
D:\George\Projects>make
gcc main.c -ID:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 -LD:\George\SDL2
-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -Wall -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o main
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libS
DL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libS
DL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libS
DL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libS
DL2.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libS
DL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib\libS
DL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libS
DL2.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible D:\George\SDL2-2.0.3\i686-w64-mingw32\lib/libS
DL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
D:/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:24: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1

D:\George\Projects>
```

If anyone can help me I would be really grateful.

Comment: Could it be a 32 / 64 bit mismatch?

Comment: Also, looks like you built SDL2 from scratch - sure that build went ok?  Do you have a ".dll" file or ".a" file called libSDL2?

Comment: I didn't built it from scratch. I've downloaded the binaries. And yes, "libSDL2.a" is in the "lib" folder.

Comment: Made it work! The problem was a 32 / 64 bit mismatch as Paul Rooney said.

Comment: Please make it a formal answer.